# How display full length of details on mouse over from truncated details in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display full length of details on mouse over from truncated details. Please suggest me how to do this. I tried `tooltip` but not showing the full length of details.

```
<table class="table">

        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.A)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Details)</th>
        </tr>  

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A)

                </td>

                <td>
                    @{
                        var Details = "";
                        if (item.Details.Length > 10)
                        {
                            Details = item.Details.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Details = item.Details;
                        }
                    }
                    <button class="link" type="button" data-id="@item.Id">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Details)
                    </button>

                </td>

            </tr>    

   }
</table>
```

Comment: You could use some css to do this - refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5ff20ev/) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want to display full details on top of the truncated details displayed in the table. So what to change in `CSS`.

Comment: What do you mean _on top of the truncated details_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, How to implement the same with my code as you have shown in  `this fiddle`. And another issue is that, in this fiddle, you are replacing the `...` with actual content once mouse hover. But I want to display on the top of content like tooltip.

Comment: Why? That is an odd UI. But you can always set the `title` attribute of the enclosing element l.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Solved using `title`. Thank you so much.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, If possible then can you please provide answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add a `title` attribute to the button

```
<button title="@item.Detail" ...>
```

Another option is to style the button to show a 'short' version by default and then toggle the 'long' version on `mouseover`

```
<button ....>
    <div class="truncate">@item.Detail </div>
</button>
```

css

```
.truncate {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.truncate').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('truncate');
})
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you so much.