# Display part of the message content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set up a web application based on sending messages, similar to a mailing application. How can I display only part of the message content (only the first 20 words, for example)

Comment: Did you check Substring method ?

Comment: You could use [.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) to truncate the value in the controller, or if you want the option to expand the message to show the full details you could use css as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477622/how-display-full-length-of-details-on-mouse-over-from-truncated-details-in-mvc-a/50480045#50480045)

Comment: `string firstTwenty = string.Concat(message?.Take(20) ?? "");`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to split your message using [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
var message = "Savvy investors would do well not to get caught up in the fluff and hype of Singles Day, Alibaba Group Holding Ltd's annual extravaganza.";
var words = message.Split().Take(20);
```

Please note that if the separator parameter is `null` or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters.

`words` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. We can use [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to concatenates the words.

So, here is the final step.

`var first20Words = string.Join(" ", words);`

The `first20Words` value will be the first 20 words of the message:

`Savvy investors would do well not to get caught up in the fluff and hype of Singles Day, Alibaba Group`.